# Function run 2 times.?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I made this program,  code successfully compiled I thought that the program takes 5 inputs from user but it takes 10 inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int greatest_number();
int main()
{
    greatest_number();
    printf("Greatest number is %d", greatest_number());
    return(0);
}

int greatest_number()
{
    int a[6], x, i, z, y;
```

I don't know why this loop takes 10 inputs from user
    even i  programmed it to take 5 inputs
        for(x=0; x<5; x++)
        {
            printf("Enter a number:");
            scanf("%d", &a[x]);
        }
        a[x]=0;
        x=0, i=1;
        y=0;
        z=a[x];
        while(a[x])
        {
            if(z>a[i]){
                z=a[y];
            }else {
                z=a[i];
                y=i;
            }
            x++;
            i++;
        }
        return(z);
       }

Comment: Please format your code. It is currently unreadable.

Comment: Unreadable - fix the indentation, (by which I mean, actually indent it).  Add a blank line between functions.

Comment: Because you call the `greatest_number` function ***two*** times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code snippet the function `greatest_number` is called twice

```
greatest_number();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
printf("Greatest number is %d", greatest_number());
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first call is redundant and its result is discarded.

Also it seems that then all entered elements have negative values (except the last element that has as I have understood a sentinel value) then the function will return the sentinel value.